# How to use request body in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, json.net

I'm doing a little project in ASP.NET MVC for the first time. I've been asked to create a REST API that does the following:

- Accept a POST request on "`/json/party/:accomodation/join`" where :accomodation is an ID

I've figured out how to make my API handle the parsing of the :accomodation parameter. I just can't figure out how to read the request body. For example, my API consumer want's to post to this URL with the following request body:

```
 { "user": 
    { 
        "name": "Hans van Dam",
        "email": "hans@test.nl",
        "straat": "Test street",
        "nummer": "10",
        "woonplaats": "Amsterdam",
        "telefoon": "0687217612",
        "newsletter": true
    },
    "party": {
        "rsvp": 1
        "time": 1370941687
    }
 }
```

Now I need to read this request body, and parse it back to objects. How can I do this in ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: Did you check the updates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC and Web API use a "modelbinder" to parse the request and provide parameters to the action method called on the controller. To accept the request body, you just need to model the JSON you're expecting and use that as a parameter to your action method.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // etc
}

public class Party
{
    public bool Rsvp { get; set; }
    // etc
}

public class JoinRequest
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Party Party { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyApiEndpoint(string accommodation, JoinRequest joinRequest)
{
    // use joinRequest, i.e.
    // joinRequest.User.Name
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Do I need to modify my route for this ? and is the model binder included by default ? or do I need to change some config for that ?

Comment: You don't need to change anything. The modelbinder searches the URL, request body, post body, etc. to try to fill up all the parameters it can.

Comment: Thanks Chris Pratt. I've got it working. It did not seem to work with a subclass of API controller however. It worked with a subclass of a normal controller. Not sure why that is. Is it possible to get it to work with that to ?

Comment: The modelbinder in ApiController is a little finicky. You can try prefixing the object parameter with `[FromBody]`, i.e. `[FromBody]JoinRequest joinRequest`. FYI, you can only use `[FromBody]` once in a ApiController action, though, since it streams the request body.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Chris Pratt.